# How to typeset slash notation and basic rhythm proposal with MusiXTex, e.g. for Jazz music?

Tags: musixtex, musicology, musixper

**My Question**: How to provide the missing musical slash symbol as a musixtex note (i.e. subjected to spacing etc.)?

Content:

- problem description
- code example
- from musixper
- SMuFL

---

Sometimes leadsheets leave the exact rhythm to the musician, denoted by slashes (red) or a kind of base pattern (orange). // Example taken from MuseScore.

How to typeset these slashes and basic rhythm proposal with `MusiXTex`, i.e. which extension to use? As far as I can see, it's

- not available in the MusiXTex manual
- not available in [musixjazz](https://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixjazz/doc/musixjazzdoc.pdf) (which is mainly about chord notation)
- not available in `musixper` (percussion).

[image: example from MuseScore]

### My code example

The first two bars show available percussion symbols in `musixper`: generic and repeat (previous bar).

In the third I tried placing the character "/" as text (`zchar{}{}`), with little success: it doesn't look right, it's not subjected to note spacing, of course. It can be tricked into it, but: it doesn't look right.

Fourth: can I take the generic whole note and just enlarge it? No, it's not available.

[image: my note example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixper

\begin{document}

 \begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
    \nobarnumbers
    \parindent0pt\startpiece
    %
    % normal generic rhythmic drum pattern suggestion
    \NOTes\zchar{13}{generic}\roqu h\roqu h\roqu h\roqu h\en\bar
    %
    % repeat previous bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{repeat}\duevolte\en\bar
    %
    % generic pattern, e.g. used with chords and chord progressions
    \NOTes\zchar{13}{generic}\zchar{3}{\textbf{/}} \zchar{3}{\textbf{/}} \zchar{3}{\textbf{/}}%
% trying "note"-adjustment  
    \off{3\elemskip}\zchar{3}{\textbf{/}}\en\bar
    %
    % can I turn this note into a slash ? no, not THIS way
    \NOTes\roqu h\en
    \endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

### From musixper

Ok, how does `musixper` deal with symbols? Here's the part which defines the `RhOmbus head notes` I used above:

```
%%% notes with a RhOmbus head, for shaker ...

\def\r@symbol{\def\q@u{\musixchar118}}

\def\roqu{\r@symbol\@qu}
\def\roql{\r@symbol\@ql}

\def\roqb{\r@symbol\@qb}

\def\rozq{\r@symbol\@zq}

\def\rocu{\r@symbol\@cu}
\def\roccu{\r@symbol\@ccu}
%\def\rocccu{\r@symbol\@cccu}
%\def\roccccu{\r@symbol\@ccccu}
\def\rocl{\r@symbol\@cl}
\def\roccl{\r@symbol\@ccl}
%\def\rocccl{\r@symbol\@cccl}
%\def\roccccl{\r@symbol\@ccccl}
```

PROBLEM: Though I could add a slash-definition here, I'd need to know which musixchar to take. It's certainly not `\musixchar118`, and I haven't found out, how to view all of them, to check availability of a slash symbol. (Following into `musixdia`, I end up at `\musixfont`, which seems to hold content I can't acces.) // I'm not experienced on this level. If I get it right, it defines new symbols by recalling previous defines and extending where needed, isn't it?

### SMuFL might provide the slash, but how to use it?

So which music font DOES provide a slash at all? I came up with SMuFL (Standard Music Font Layout, free)

- here's the hint [(MuseScore at github)](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/tree/master/fonts)
- here's [SMuFL](https://www.w3.org/2021/03/smufl14/) and the [relevant glyph table](https://www.w3.org/2021/03/smufl14/tables/slash-noteheads.html) (and the [unicode link](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf))

Looking through it, it DOES provide the slash symbol I'm after as `01D10D`, `U+E101` or `U+1D10D`:

[image: excerpt1]
[image: excerpt2]

**My Question again**: How to put this all together to provide the missing musical slash symbol as a musixtex note (i.e. subjected to spacing etc.)?

Comment: have look at https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/learning/other-templates and the lilypond package see if this gets you where to start.

Comment: Thanks @PaulA, but my question is about MusiXTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\zchar` approach already comes quite close. You just need `\sk` (skip horizontally by one `\noteskip`) between the slashes.

To get a nice slash from a music font you can use Emmentaler from Lilypond (download at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/unicodetex/latex/lilyglyphs/fonts if you don't have the `lilyglyphs` package installed), which has a named glyph `noteheads.s2slash`.

Code below for XeLaTeX, for LuaLaTeX change the relevant lines to use `documentdata.fontchar`. For comparison also a `/` character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\lilyfont{emmentaler-14.otf}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlily}{\lilyfont}
\newcommand{\simile}{\textlily{\LARGE\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"noteheads.s2slash"}}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\nobarnumbers
\startextract
\Notes\qu{g}\zchar{4}{\simile}\sk\zchar{4}{\simile}\sk\zchar{4}{\simile}\sk\en
\bar
\Notes\qu{'a}\zchar{3}{/}\sk\zchar{3}{/}\sk\zchar{3}{/}\sk\en
\setdoublebar
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Result:

### [image]

For pdfLaTeX you could try a fake bold slash. It doesn't have straight edges, and it is more upright than the Lilypond version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[bold=1]{xfakebold}
\newcommand{\simile}{\setBold/\unsetBold}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\nobarnumbers
\startextract
\Notes\qu{g}\zchar{3}{\simile}\sk\zchar{3}{\simile}\sk\zchar{3}{\simile}\sk\en
\bar
\Notes\qu{'a}\zchar{3}{/}\sk\zchar{3}{/}\sk\zchar{3}{/}\sk\en
\setdoublebar
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]